# How to get departure time and arrival time from 2 different relation in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Model is transport system:

nodes: BusStop, Bus, TransportOperator

Relationship : Bus-[Operated_By]->TransportOperator

Relationship : BusStop-[:Stops_At]->Bus

relationship STOPS_AT has 2 properties arrival time(9:00) and departure time(9:01) connected to all the busstop.

Example: Bus number 34 is connected to BusStop1(ArrTime-9:00, DeptTime-9:01), BusStop2(ArrTime-9:10, DeptTime-9:11), BusStop3(ArrTime-9:15, DeptTime-9:16)

If i use the below query i get an out put as :

```
enter code here

MATCH (a:BusStop{name:'Bonhoefferstrasse'}),(d:BusStop {name:'HeidelBerg Hauptbanhof'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d))
WITH p, FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE x:Bus) AS buses
UNWIND buses AS Bus
MATCH (Bus)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o:TransportOperator)
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:BusStop THEN 'BusStop' + x.name
    WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus' + x.id
    ELSE '' END) AS itinerary,
COLLECT ('Bus' + Bus.id+ ':' + 'TransportOperator' + o.name) AS Operators
```

Output:

itinerary:
BusStopBonhoefferstrasse, Bus34, BusStopHeidelBerg Hauptbanhof

Operators:
Bus34:TransportOperatorRhein-Neckar-Verkehr

Expected output:

itinerary: BusStopBonhoefferstrasse **DeptTime:9:01**, Bus34,RNV, BusStopHeidelBerg Hauptbanhof **ArrTime:9:15**

Operators:
Bus34: TransportOperatorRhein-Neckar-Verkehr

Comment: The question states: `BusStop-[:Stops_At]->Bus`. Should this actually be `Bus-[:Stops_At]->BusStop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go again:

```
CREATE (a:Stop {name:'A'}),
       (b:Stop {name:'B'}),
       (c:Stop {name:'C'}),
       (d:Stop {name:'D'}),

       (a)-[:NEXT {distance:1}]->(b),
       (b)-[:NEXT {distance:2}]->(c),
       (c)-[:NEXT {distance:3}]->(d),

       (b1:Bus {id:1}),
       (b2:Bus {id:2}),
       (b3:Bus {id:3}),

       (o1:Operator {id:1}),
       (o2:Operator {id:2}),

       (b1)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o1),
       (b2)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o1),
       (b3)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o2),

       (b1)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:00', departure:'9:01'}]->(a),
       (b1)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:10', departure:'9:11'}]->(b),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:05', departure:'9:06'}]->(a),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:20', departure:'9:21'}]->(b),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:29', departure:'9:30'}]->(c),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:45', departure:'9:46'}]->(b),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:50', departure:'9:51'}]->(c),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT {arrival:'9:57', departure:'9:58'}]->(d);
```

You should just return the departure and arrival time as their own columns:

```
MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (d:Stop {name:'D'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d))
WITH p, FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE x:Bus) AS buses
UNWIND buses AS bus
MATCH (bus)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o:Operator)
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                    WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus ' + x.id
                               ELSE '' END) AS itinerary,
       HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).departure AS departure_time,
       LAST(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).arrival AS arrival_time,
       COLLECT('Bus ' + bus.id + ':' + 'Operator ' + o.id) AS operators
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/x8fx3b

Comment: And I like the notion of returning the departure and arival times in their own columns; nicer for post processing.

Comment: Hello Nicole, the above query returns me the arrival & dept time but the issue is that for BusStop B i have 2 bus connected so the in output im getting the other bus detail which are connected to stop B - 


itinerary departure_time arrival_time operators
BusStop Bonhoefferstrasse, Bus 34, BusStop HeidelBerg Hauptbanhof 8:56 9:15 Bus34:TransportOperatorRhein-Neckar-Verkehr, Bus35:TransportOperatorRhein-Neckar-Verkehr, Bus357:TransportOperatorBEST

Comment: I would like the operator to display only one bus 1, can i have a filter condition to display only Bus 1 (Now its displaying all the bus in my graph)

Comment: If you need further help you'll need to provide a console example of your dataset. console.neo4j.org

Comment: The same query worked with little modifications... Thanks nicole

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over the collection of nodes in your path, you could iterate over the collection of relationships.

I think that something like this will return the result you are seeking.

```
...
EXTRACT(s IN relationships(p) | CASE 
WHEN 'BusStop' in labels(startNode(s)) THEN 'BusStop' + (startNode(s)).name + ' ' + s.DepTime
WHEN 'BusStop' in labels(endNode(s)) THEN 'BusStop' + (endNode(s)).name + ' ' + s.ArrTime
WHEN 'Bus' in labels(startNode(s)) THEN 'Bus' + (startNode(s)).name
ELSE '' END) AS itinerary
...
```

Comment: I like this solution for returning the departure and arrival times within the itinerary column.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misread the data model, so this answer doesn't actually work.

====================================================

It looks like the problem is in your return statement. You're explicitly saying to only return the string 'BusStop' concatenated with the bus stop name.

You could change your extract statement to return the arrival and departure times, but getting the arrival time only on the first node and the departure time only on the last node would likely require rethinking your query. Here's what you need to add the arrival time to your results across the board. This isn't exactly what you need based on your expected output, but should give you a good idea why no times are being ouput:

```
EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE 
WHEN x:BusStop THEN 'BusStop' + x.name + ' ' + x.ArrTime
WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus' + x.id
ELSE '' END) AS itinerary
```

Comment: It looks like the departure time and arrival time are on the `:STOPS_AT` relationship and not the bus stop node so that won't work per the OP's data model.

Comment: Ah, I misread one of the lines, thanks for catching that @DaveBennett